# Using :before and :after attributes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure on how use to `:after` and `:before` CSS properly and will be applying the styles to this:

[image]

The objective here is to fit the fixed width and height of box inside of the parent box (not sure if I said that correctly).

The box inside is going past or overflowing.

How do I set the parent box to adjust no matter how big the child box is? The child box I'm mentioning here is the dark grey box.

```html
<div class="connections-label">
    <div class="connections-avatar"></div>
    <h3><a href="">Christian Blanquera</a></h3>
    <h4>Invested over 5 million cookies in 20 startups</h4>
</div>
```

```css
.connections-label a 
{
    color:#1c89cc; 
    text-decoration:none
}

.connections-label h4
{
    color:#686868;
    font-style:italic;
}

.connections-avatar
{
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    float:left; 
    background-color:grey; 
    margin-right:10px
}

.connections-label:after
{
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: I do not understand.. as far as I can see, according to your image, what you want is a box partly behind another (and some txt). I made a fiddle of your code, please advice as what you really want: http://jsfiddle.net/JQcwz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a CSS clearfix solution. Basically, floated elements are removed from the normal flow of the document, and must be [contained](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/). The simplest clearfix is to apply `overflow: hidden;` to the element containing the floated element:

```
.connections-label {
  overflow: hidden; }
```

This is usually sufficient for most float containment scenarios. However, positioned elements and overflowing content will also be clipped by this CSS. A more complex clearfix will contain floated elements without hiding positioned elements is documented at the article above:

```
.connections-label:before,
.connections-label:after {
  content: '';
  display: table; }
.connections-label:after {
  clear: both; }

/* IE6/7 support */
.connections-label {
  display: inline-block; }
.connections-label {
  display: block; }
```

Also, another trick I learned recently is that applying `overflow: hidden;` to an element on the left or right of a floated element keeps that element from wrapping below the floated element. It's easier to see than describe, so check out my [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5hk2q/).